# Regex as key in Dictionary in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, dictionary

Is there a way to use `Regex` as a key in a `Dictionary`?  Something like `Dictionary(Of Regex, String)`?

I'm trying to find a `Regex` in a list (let's say that there is no dictionary for the first time) by string, which it matches.

I can do it by manually iterating through the list of RegEx expressions.  I'm just seeking for a method to do that more easily, such as `TryGetValue` from a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Maybe you want the opposite, the key as string and the value as regex. That sounds more useful.

Comment: Do you need equality of pattern and options etc? I don't know offhand whether Regex overrides Equals.

Comment: Yes, but to what end?  Why would you do that?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Tell more about what you're trying to do, as well.  Do you want to use a regex object as a key, and match the whole object later to lookup a value?  Or are you trying to have some kind of "loose" or "fuzzy" key lookup?  Or...

Comment: @ArlaudPierre, Yes, "Dictionary(Of Regex, String)" don't the trick.

Comment: What "trick"?  It does work, just probably not the way you expect it to.  You need to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MikeM, There is a list (let's think there is not a dictionary) of regexp's. I should find regexp by string. Ok. I will do it myself.

Comment: Do regex actually have an hashcode?

Comment: there's no problem using objects in a .net dictionary.  Try it and update your question if you have any problems.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Regex` as the type for the key in a `Dictionary`, it will work, but it compares the key by object instance, not by the expression string.  In other words, if you create two separate `Regex` objects, using the same expression for both, and then add them to the dictionary, they will be treated as two different keys (because they are two different objects).

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of Regex, String)()
Dim r As New Regex(".*")
Dim r2 As New Regex(".*")
d(r) = "1"
d(r2) = "2"
d(r) = "overwrite 1"
Console.WriteLine(d.Count)  ' Outputs "2"
```

If you want to use the expression as the key, rather than the `Regex` object, then you need to create your dictionary with a key type of `String`, for instance:

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
d(".*") = "1"
d(".*") = "2"
d(".*") = "3"
Console.WriteLine(d.Count)  ' Outputs "1"
```

Then, when you are using the expression string as the key, you can use `TryGetValue`, like you described:

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
d(".*") = "1"
Dim value As String = Nothing

' Outputs "1"
If d.TryGetValue(".*", value) Then
    Console.WriteLine(value)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Not found")
End If

' Outputs "Not found"
If d.TryGetValue(".+", value) Then
    Console.WriteLine(value)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Not found")
End If
```

Comment: could you take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73072887/9599896). My question is similar, but I am trying to essentially write 6 regex groups into a dictionary. Thank you!