# vb.net Read using reader, return data based on regex match and put that into data structure

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to return all of the read data into an efficient data structure. The reader is doing it's job and returning the correct values from my regex. Now I am trying to store that data in memory and parse later. I want to do this in one  button click event.

```
Sub ReadFile()
        Dim mapping As New Mapping()
        Dim variable As New MappingVariable()
        Dim P, line, startPosition, totalLength, id, name, number As String
        Dim m As Match
        Dim reader As New StreamReader("..\..\..\FileName.myp", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
        Do
            line = reader.ReadLine
            If line Is Nothing Then Continue Do
            m = Regex.Match(line, "^\[(\w+)\]")
            P = m.Groups(1).ToString()
            mapping.P = P
            ' Grab that code
            If m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
                ' Read the next line after the code and get the 4 digits
                line = reader.ReadLine
                m = Regex.Match(line, "ID=\w\w(\w\w\w\w)")
                id = m.Groups(1).ToString()
                mapping.id = ID
                ' Then keep reading until the next blank line
                Do
                    line = reader.ReadLine
                    If line Is Nothing Then Continue Do
                    m = Regex.Match(line, ".*?(\d+),(\d+).*?\""(.+?)\"".*?(\d+) .*")
                    If m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
                        startPosition = m.Groups(1).ToString()
                        variable.startPosition = startPosition
                        totalLength = m.Groups(2).ToString()
                        variable.totalLength = totalLength
                        name = m.Groups(3).ToString()
                        variable.name = Name
                        number = m.Groups(4).ToString()
                        variable.number = number
                    End If
                Loop Until line = ""
            End If
        Loop Until line Is Nothing
        Console.WriteLine($"{mapping.p} - P")
        Console.WriteLine($"{mapping.id} - ID")
        For Each variables As MappingVariable In mapping.Variables
            Console.WriteLine($"{variable.startPosition} - startPosition")
            Console.WriteLine($"{variable.totalLength} - totalLength")
            Console.WriteLine($"{variable.name} - name")
            Console.WriteLine($"{variable.number} - number")
        reader.Close()
    End Sub
```

Button Function:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

'New code to return a mapping object in order to write the desired output.
        Dim Test As New List(Of Mapping)

'The code used to call the reader
        Dim Testing = New ReadFile
        Testing.WriteToTempFile()
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly was the problem with dic.Add(line, m.Groups)?

Comment: I was getting only the `var` line from text structure and even then it was the entire line, not separated (i.e., position, length, name, number). I would like it to store every match when found, like it does when reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what exactly you're trying to do, but my guess is that you want to turn this into a function which returns all the data that was read from the file, in some kind of meaningful and easily readable data structure.  I haven't tested it, but the algorithm for reading the data out of the file and parsing it with regex looks right, so if you say that part of it is working, I believe you.  The problem is that you seem to be having trouble with how to store the data as objects in memory.

The first step is to design a class which declares the structure the data is going to take in memory.  What that should look like will depend on your needs, and I don't know what those are, so I'll make some assumptions.  Hopefully my example will be useful in at least giving you a starting point.

The following class can be used to hold the data from each `Var=` line:

```
Public Class MappingVariable
    Public Property StartPosition As String
    Public Property TotalLength As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Number As String
End Class
```

And the following class can be used to store the whole mapping (note that it includes the `Variables` property which is typed as a list of our `MappingVariable` class):

```
Public Class Mapping
    Public Property P As String
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Variables As New List(Of MappingVariable)()
End Class
```

Now, in the code, you can start by creating a `Mapping` object and filling it in with the header data that was read (before it starts reading the `Var=` lines):

```
Dim mapping As New Mapping()
mapping.P = p
mapping.Id = id
```

Then, after reading the data from each `Var=` line, you can create a `MappingVariable` object and add it to the mapping's `Variables` list:

```
Dim variable As New MappingVariable()
variable.StartPosition = startPosition
variable.TotalLength = totalLength 
variable.Name = name 
variable.Number = number 
mapping.Variables.Add(variable)
```

It's not clear whether the file contains multiple mappings or just one.  If it contains just one, you could have the function return a `Mapping` object.  If it can contain multiple, you could add them to a list after populating them and then have the function return a `List(Of Mapping)` object.

In any case, once you have the `Mapping` object, you can write the desired output from it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{mapping.P} - P")
Console.WriteLine($"{mapping.Id} - ID")
For Each(variable As MappingVariable in mapping.Variables)
    Console.WriteLine($"{variable.StartPosition} - startPosition")
    Console.WriteLine($"{variable.TotalLength} - totalLength")
    Console.WriteLine($"{variable.Name} - name")
    Console.WriteLine($"{variable.Number} - number")
Next
```

There's all sorts of improvements that could be made to that, of course.  You probably ought to have at least the position and length properties be typed as integers rather than strings, for instance.  You may also want the variables stored in a dictionary, keyed by their name, number, or position for quicker access.  But hopefully that's enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

### Update

You're getting there, but you have things in the wrong place.  Allow me to revise your code:

```
Function ReadFile() As List(Of Mapping)  ' Note that I changed this to a function and I have it returning a list of mappings
    Dim mappings As New List(Of Mapping)()
    Dim P, line, startPosition, totalLength, id, name, number As String
    Dim m As Match
    Dim reader As New StreamReader("..\..\..\FileName.myp", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
    Do
        Dim mapping As New Mapping()  ' Create a new mapping object for each one in the file rather than only creating it once at the top of the function
        line = reader.ReadLine
        If line Is Nothing Then Continue Do
        m = Regex.Match(line, "^\[(\w+)\]")
        P = m.Groups(1).ToString()
        mapping.P = P
        ' Grab that code
        If m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
            ' Read the next line after the code and get the 4 digits
            line = reader.ReadLine
            m = Regex.Match(line, "ID=\w\w(\w\w\w\w)")
            id = m.Groups(1).ToString()
            mapping.id = ID
            ' Then keep reading until the next blank line
            Do
                line = reader.ReadLine
                If line Is Nothing Then Continue Do
                m = Regex.Match(line, ".*?(\d+),(\d+).*?\""(.+?)\"".*?(\d+) .*")
                If m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
                    Dim variable As New MappingVariable()  ' Create a new variable object for each Var= line rather than just creating one at the top of the function
                    startPosition = m.Groups(1).ToString()
                    variable.startPosition = startPosition
                    totalLength = m.Groups(2).ToString()
                    variable.totalLength = totalLength
                    name = m.Groups(3).ToString()
                    variable.name = Name
                    number = m.Groups(4).ToString()
                    variable.number = number
                    mapping.Variables.Add(variable)  ' Add this populated variable to this mapping's list of variables
                End If
            Loop Until line = ""
            mappings.Add(mapping)  ' Add this populated mapping to the list
        End If
    Loop Until line Is Nothing
    reader.Close()
    Return mappings  ' Return the list of mappings that were read from the file back to whatever was calling this function
End Function


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mappings As List(Of Mapping) = ReadFile()
    For Each mapping As Mapping in mappings
        Console.WriteLine($"{mapping.p} - P")
        Console.WriteLine($"{mapping.id} - ID")
        For Each variables As MappingVariable In mapping.Variables
            Console.WriteLine($"{variable.startPosition} - startPosition")
            Console.WriteLine($"{variable.totalLength} - totalLength")
            Console.WriteLine($"{variable.name} - name")
            Console.WriteLine($"{variable.number} - number")
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are a beast! I updated my question and code (your recommendations), thank you for articulating my question better than me HA. I am following what you are saying to an extent. The file contains A LOT of mappings. I ran my code above and it grabbed 1 mapping and repeated the same variables over and over again. I would assume I have misplaced some code on different lines, but I figured typing it out would help you. Also, (still new to this), my button function to return object is ~ incorrect? I need to read up on where this is actually being "stored". Great start though thanks

Comment: *Clarifying what I meant by repeating. I got below. After number, it repeated the same start, total, name and number again. I would like to grab P and ID return all the `var` matches, then go to the next P and ID and do the same until the end.                                                                   
XXXX - P
XXXX - ID
XX - startPosition
XX - totalLength
XX - name
XX - number -- then it repeated here.

Comment: @Lord45 I updated my answer with more examples :)

Comment: this worked! Perfectly. I see how you fixed the areas of where the mappings go. This might be a dumb question, but now the data is stored in memory? In order to search through this, I will have another function that reads through the list? Thank you :) This helps a bunch - accepting answer.

Comment: Yes, when it's in a variable, it's in memory.  The class is a convenient way to describe a data structure that is stored in memory.  By specifying all it's fields, you're letting the compiler know how much memory needs to be allocated for each object of that class (i.e. each new instance created with that class as its type) and how the meaning and format of the data within that allocated block of memory.  That's what the `New` keyword does.  It allocates memory for a new object of the given class.

Comment: As far as how to read it, that's what that button click method is doing.  It's reading through the mappings in memory and outputting them to the console.  If you need to find a specific mapping, or variable, you'd need to loop through them, checking the properties on each one, until you find the one you're looking for.  If you want to learn LINQ and lambdas, you can do it more conveniently in a single line (e.g. `Dim mappingP = mappings.FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.P = "P")`).  In reality, that's still looping through all the objects, so it's not really any faster, just easier to read/write.

Comment: @Lord45 If there are many objects loaded into memory, looping through them can become prohibitively slow.  If that becomes an issue, you should consider indexing them for quicker access with a `Dictionary` or `HashTable`.

Comment: @SteveDoggart, I see. That is why at first I tried to use the Dictionary, but it wasn't working as expected but that was mainly due to user error. I might be posting a new question for Dictionary if I get stuck - be on the lookout lol Thanks again for guidance and explanation.

Comment: I messaged you on Codementor! Thank you.